# Using GREP and Inotifywait

Tags: linux, grep

I have this small script and I was wondering if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong. It is basically watching a folder, and if a file with `.php.something-else` is uploaded, it should be deleted.

How do I get grep the file name? 
Essentially, I want to check if FILE has an extention .php.something-else.

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create /samplefolder | while read FILE
do
      if grep '*.php.* ; then  <<-----HERE, I WANT THE FILE NAME
         /bin/rm $FILE
      fi     
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need grep. Check for the file's existence and delete it:

```
if [ -f *.php.* ] ; then 
     /bin/rm $FILE
  fi
```

---

You can use `case` to match it:

```
case $FILE in
*.php.*)
     /bin/rm $FILE
esac
```

Comment: Thanks. But f is not found. How can I check if FILE has .php.something-else extention?

Comment: @HelenNeely Updated my answer. `case` can help with matching the file name.

Comment: please take care with the $FILE, you need to escape it, as someone can create a file with wildcards and then the party is over. ``` echo '*' > '*' ```